# AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange when this notification is post in swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, avcapturedevice

I'm working on a camera app and I'm trying to center the focus of the camera to the center using this notification, [AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1624619-avcapturedevicesubjectareadidcha).

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didChangeSubjectArea(_:)), name: .AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: nil)

@objc func didChangeSubjectArea(_ notification: Notification) {
    setFocusToCenter()
}
```

It's kind of working now, like the didChangeSubjectArea is triggered when I move the device around. But I'm still not sure when exactly, or in what kind of situation the AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange is triggered, because, on the document, it says

> A notification the system posts when a capture device detects a substantial change to the video subject area.

Now I'm confused what the `a substantial change to the video subject area` can be, other than moving the camera around or tilting the camera. If anyone knows other substantial changes to the video subject area, could you tell me and where you find the source?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624644-issubjectareachangemonitoringena) provides a bit more information about what it's looking for. Namely, changes to lighting, camera movement, objects moving in/out of focal range, etc.  This method is intended to provide you an opportunity to adjust camera device settings relative to the changes in the scene detected by the hardware, such as adjusting focus/white balance/exposure configuration.